# How to add the kill button in xfce4-panel 4.10.0 of Xubuntu 12.10?

Tags: xubuntu, process, kill, 12.10, xfce-panel

When I was using Gnome 2, I had the option of add a kill button on the panel, but on xfce4-panel 4.10.0 this button is not an option, I think it's necessary add it manually, creating a new luncher. But how can I do that? I don't know which is the processes that should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new launcher, type `xkill` into command field.